# Parse lists which can contain parentheses with ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer, parentheses, s-expression

Lets say I want to create a grammar that is similar to Lisp where all expressions are between open and close parentheses.

For example:

```
(+ 1 2)
```

I also want the grammar to be able to parse the string `('(def foo))` to a parse tree which is similar to `(expression ( literal '(def foo) ))`.
That means it should successfully associate the parentheses in the literal expression to the literal.

Comment: Would love to help.   Show us your grammar so far so we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

Well, LISP in general is very user-extensible in terms of its grammar, so I don't know how possible it would be to get any BNF(+) form of it. [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.lisp/_JYqG712WvU/0qw4KXTPVZQJ) is a discussion about it; I'm sure there are more if you search for it.

But for toy examples, this will probably be fine:

```
<s_expression>  ::= <atomic_symbol>
              | "(" <s_expression> "." <s_expression> ")"
              | <list> .

<_list>         ::= <s_expression> <_list>
              | <s_expression> .

<list>          ::= "(" <s_expression> <_list> ")" .

<atomic_symbol> ::= <letter> <atom_part> | "'"  <s_expression> .

<atom_part>     ::= <empty> | <letter> <atom_part> | <number> <atom_part> .

<letter>        ::= "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" | "j"
              | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t"
              | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z" .

<number>        ::= "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | "0" .

<empty>         ::= " ".
```

[modified from here](https://github.com/arrdem/sad/blob/master/test/lisp.bnf)

I modified the grammar in a hurry, so please tell me if you see any problems with it.

Also, I haven't used ANTLR in a long time, so I don't know if it's exactly in a format it excepts. But it should be trivial to format it right though.